# Windows Docker Container MSMQ outqueue messages never reaches destination

Tags: windows, docker, containers, msmq

**UPDATE with Steps to solution:**

I built a dummy console app that basically just reads and writes from MSMQ. The main issue was ensuring authentication is set on the destination server MSMQ queues itself that you are connecting to from within the container. 
So if you want to read from a private queue called gw.in and write to a private queue gw.out, both the queues needs to have user permissions "*Everyone*" and "*ANONYMOUS LOGON*" set to "*FullControl*" for both queues. Now the docker container can read and write from the queues as expected.
The other minor thing I missed was ensuring the MSMQ path name string is formatted correctly, for example

```
FORMATNAME:DIRECT=TCP:{ip address}\private$\gw.in
```

or

```
FORMATNAME:DIRECT=OS:{dns name}\private$\gw.in
```

*(Basically the same as you would run from 1 server connecting to another.)*

The only problem I have now is how safe is this for production as this would need to be rolled out to production services at some point.

**UPDATE 2: Link to working sample app and dockerfile** https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1278439/Working-with-MSMQ-in-Windows-Docker-Containers

In case someone else wanted to play as well.

**Original post below**

I have created a Windows docker image. A simple application service starts when the container is created, receiving messages on a udp connection (9005), doing some data manipulation and then writing the results out to MSMQ. (Old application unfortunately.. Cant remove MSMQ even if I wanted to... )

Now the problem comes in when connecting to the destination MSMQ Queue on another server. 
When I run the container as interactive, I can trace through the usual powershell commands etc that data is coming in and being written to MSMQ Outqueue. At which point MSMQ tells me it can't connect to the destination or the destination queue doesn't exist and the outqueue messages are dropped and disappears into thin air.

```
# escape=`
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:1803
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MSMQ-Server -All
COPY . C:\app
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
WORKDIR C:\app\Deployment
RUN .\deploy.ps1
EXPOSE 9005/udp 7998/tcp 1801/tcp 3527/udp 1801/udp 389/tcp 135/udp 135/tcp 2101/tcp 2103/tcp 2105/tcp
```

MSMQ ports as per https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/178517/tcp-ports-udp-ports-and-rpc-ports-that-are-used-by-message-queuing

Sample docker run command (out of frustration with multiple -p mappings etc, obviously already tried with specifics):

```
docker run -it -p 9005:9005/udp -p 7998:7998 -p 9004:9004/udp -p 1801:1801 -p 389:389 -p 2101:2101 -p 2103:2103 -p 2105:2105  028cf678fec8
```

I have updated the above dockerfile and run cmd so many times, playing with different ports, exposing ports and when running the container adding different variances. The above is the last one where i tried all ports. 
However I can not get MSMQ to write to the destination MSMQ server queues from within the container to the destination.
I can write to a private queue within the container, but that is obviously pointless as the container is not suppose to have state, but rather just the processor...

Can anyone please help. What am I missing.
Thanks

Comment: If anyone wants the dummy app with dockerfile etc Ill gladly share it. :)

Comment: "The only problem I have now is how safe is this for production as this would need to be rolled out to production services at some point." What do you mean by 'safe'? There is no security on the queues so it's unsafe from that perspective.

Comment: @JohnBreakwell Yeah I suppose it comes down to permission to write too and read from the queues.